# Veronese map property

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Consider the Veronese map $v_2,_2$: $\mathbb{P^2}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\mathbb{P^5}$.
I'm asked to show that all lines in $\mathbb{P^2}$ are mapped into conics contained in some subspace M of $\mathbb{P^5}$.

I get that M is a $\mathbb{P^2}$$\subset$$\mathbb{P^5}$, so the image of a line L is some plane curve. How do I formalize it?
And then, how do I say that the image is actually a conic, and not a cubic or something else?

Any hint or solution sketch would be great :)

Comment: Your question  remind me  of  the fact that the  pull back of  the tautological line  bundle $\ell$ under Veronese embedding is  in the form $\ell^k$ for some  appropriate $k$ depending on the dimension of the underline projective spaces. By $\ell^k$ we mean the k-fold tensor product. I  do not remember the reference but one can find  it via google seracch "The pull back of  tautoligical line  bundle under Veronese embedding" may be the idea of proof can be related to your question.

Comment: or  googling "the  pull back of  canaonical line  bundle under Veronese embedding"  or  some things like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Let $p=x^2$, $q=y^2$, $r=z^2$, $u=y z$, $v=x z$, $w=x y$. Consider the equation of a line $a x + b y + c z = 0$. We conclude the following equalities:
$$a p + b w + c v = 0\\
a w + b q + c u = 0\\
a v + b u + c r = 0\\
a v w + b u w + c u v =0$$
Note that we can change the system of coordinates of $\mathbb{P}^2$ so that $a$, $b$, $c$ are all non-zero.